# Logical Equivalence Exact Definition

Tags: logic

We say that two statements are [logically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) if and only if they have the same truth value in every model. I am wanting to be precise with this definition and was wondering if this is the same thing as the following: two sentences $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are said to be logically equivalent, denoted $\Gamma_1\equiv \Gamma_2$, if and only if $\Gamma_1\models \Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_2 \models \Gamma_1$. I am also curious is there a difference between saying a statement and a sentence here. Any help would be appreciated.

> A sentence $\varphi$ is said to be a $\textbf{logical consequence}$ of a set of sentences $\Gamma$, denoted $\Gamma \models \varphi$, if and only if there does not exist a model $\mathcal{I}$ in which all members of $\Gamma$ are true and $\varphi$ is false.

Comment: Yes, those are the same conditions, but this is not obvious; it follows from the completeness theorem.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by $\models$ here? (If $A$ and $B$ are sentences, most people write $A \models B$ to mean every model of $A$ is a model of $B$, so your question is trivial with that reading of $\models$.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: as the question appears to make no reference to proof, what has the completeness theorem got to do with it?

Comment: I am voting to close this pending clarification of the use of the symbol  $\models$.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I misread the question.

Comment: @RobArthan A sentence $\varphi$ is said to be a $\textbf{logical consequence}$ of a set of sentences $\Gamma$, denoted $\Gamma \models \varphi$, if and only if there does not exist a model $\mathcal{I}$ in which all members of $\Gamma$ are true and $\varphi$ is false.

Comment: I just wanted to know if they were the same.The intent of the question was not directed at the proof. I think it would be neat to see the proof, but that was not the intent of the question.

Comment: @W.G.: so now you've given the definitions, your question is trivial as regards sentences (statements with no free variables). My point about proof was to do with the possibility that you'd written $\models$ by mistake for $\vdash$ (for provability), Please ask a better question!

Comment: It is fine; see a good ML textbbok, like e.g. [Enderton's one](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA88), page 88: "Let $\Gamma$ be a set of formulas, $\varphi$ a formula. Then $\Gamma$ *logically implies* $\varphi$, written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, iff for every structure $\mathfrak A$ for the language and
every variable assignment function $s$ such that $A$ satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ with $s$ (written: $s, \mathfrak A \vDash \psi$), $\mathfrak A$ also satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$." 1/2

Comment: "As before we will write “$\psi \vDash \varphi$” in place of “$\{ \psi \} \vDash \varphi$.” Say that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are *logically equivalent* iff $\varphi \vDash \psi$ and $\psi \vDash \varphi$." 2/2

Comment: With *sentences* (i.e. formulas without free occurrences of variables) we can simply remove the variable assignment function $s$ from the above definitions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Is it okay if I represent it as follows: Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be formulas. Thus,  $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent  iff $\lbrace \varphi \rbrace \vDash \psi$ and $\lbrace \psi \rbrace \vDash \varphi$. I just want to be consistent with $\Gamma$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There are two people that I can always count on for logic help, and you are absolutely one of them. Every time I post a question, it seems to be answered by you or Bram28. I see your name pop up and know something is answered correctly. Would you mind if I cited you as a source if I use any definitions/content we discuss on this site? It is okay if you say no as well. I just wanted to let you know that I appreciate your help.

Comment: 1. Obviously $\{ \varphi \} \vDash \psi$ is fine. 2. Thanks :-) 3. No problem: the definitions are not "mine": you can find them in the textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these two definitions are equivalent. Here is a proof:

From 'left' to 'right':

Assume that in every model, $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ have the same truth-value. This means that there is no model where $\Gamma_1$ is true and $\Gamma_2$ is flase, and hence $\Gamma_1 \vDash \Gamma_2$. Likewise, there is no model where $\Gamma_2$ is true and $\Gamma_2$ is false, and hence $\Gamma_2 \vDash \Gamma_1$

From 'right' to 'left':

Assume $\Gamma_1 \vDash \Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_2 \vDash \Gamma_1$. This means that there is no model where $\Gamma _1$ is true and $\Gamma_2$ is false, and there is also no model where $\Gamma _2$ is true and $\Gamma_1$ is false. So, there is no model where $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ have different truth_values, for if there were such a model, then in that model one of them would be true and the other false, and we just determined that there are no such models. Hence, in every model $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ have the same truth-value.

Comment: Would you mind if I cited you as a source if I use any definitions/content we discuss on this site as well? I just wanted to let you know that I truly appreciate your help. I have given the answer to you, because it explains it more. Just to be particular, can it be the following where $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are formulas and are logically equivalent iff $\lbrace \varphi \rbrace \vDash \psi$ and $\lbrace \psi \rbrace \vDash \varphi$. I just worry about them being sentences here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is an equivalent definition.

This is assuming that every statement can be written as a sentence in formal logic and *vice versa*.

Typically, a statement is more general than a sentence.

Comment: (I could be wrong.)

Comment: Do you know of any difference between saying statement and sentence here?

Comment: I've updated the answer, @W.G.

Comment: @W.G.: The relevant difference between statement (or formula) and sentence is to do with the occurrence of free variables. But as you have accepted a vague answer and have not clarified an important lacuna in your question, I assume you are not interested in the details.

Comment: You're right, @RobArthan: my answer is a little vague. Would you mind answering it yourself, please? I'd like to see a better attempt . . .

Comment: @Shaun: will do if the OP does their bit and clarifies what's meant by $\models$.

Comment: They've done so, @RobArthan.